# Riemann integral of a certain function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\{q_n\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$. Define $f$ on $[0,1]$ by $f(x):=\sum_{q_n<x}2^{-n}$.

It has already been shown by Lebesgue's Criterion that $f$ is Riemann integrable. Now we're supposed to compute the integral. We've tried constructing partitions based on the enumeration, but nothing has worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$ f = \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} 2^{-n}\chi_{(q_n, 1]} $$
and the convergence is uniform, hence integration and summation can be exchanged, giving
$$ \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \sum_n 2^{-n} \int_0^1 \chi_{(q_n, 1]}(x)\, dx = \sum_n 2^{-n}(1 - q_n). $$